# Dependency relationship in UML

Tags: uml, relationship

in UML there is Dependency relationship,However I read the following quote:

`dependency indicates a semantic relationship between two or more elements`

## what does `semantic relationship` mean in the above sentence?

Comment: **se·man·tic**  (s-mntk) also **se·man·ti·cal** (-t-kl)
adj.
1. *Of or relating to meaning, especially meaning in language.*

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey! Do you know what Carlos means by functional relationship?

Comment: I am looking for example about functional relationship in UML?

Answer (score 1):

means that this kind of relationship is bounded by some kind of semantic definition between the elements, meaning that this semantic definition defines the UML relationship and gives it meaning. Always remember two kind of relationships: functional and semantic.

Comment: please give an example about functional relationship in UML?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcdepend.html

Comment: thanks to you @amitesh, Do you know what Carlos means by functional relationship?

Comment: @Chriss nope chriss i not able to understand what carlos want to say may if he give u an example it will help you to understand what he is trying to say